# How do I wrap tags inside of for loop using jquery Ajax with json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I practice Ajax using jQuery.

I am stack now to figure out how to output json data with jQuery for-loop. How can I output tags and even wrap tags inside of for-loop?

HTML tags come out like this:

```
<main>
  <h1>Ajax</h1>
  <div id="output">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <h3>Card Title</h3>
      <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="Alt"></p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <h3>Card Title</h3>
      <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="Alt"></p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <h3>Card Title</h3>
      <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="Alt"></p>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <h3>Card Title</h3>
      <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="Alt"></p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <h3>Card Title</h3>
      <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="Alt"></p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <h3>Card Title</h3>
      <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="Alt"></p>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /#output -->
</main>
```

But I'd like to wrap `block`, `card` div tags to contain `h3` .etc tags in those.
Ideally I want html to be like this:

```
<main>
  <h1>Ajax</h1>
  <div id="output">
    <div class="block">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="card">
          <h3>Card Title</h3>
          <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="Alt"></p>
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h3>Card Title</h3>
          <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="Alt"></p>
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h3>Card Title</h3>
          <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="Alt"></p>
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="card">
          <h3>Card Title</h3>
          <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="Alt"></p>
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h3>Card Title</h3>
          <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="Alt"></p>
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h3>Card Title</h3>
          <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="Alt"></p>
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /#output -->
</main>
```

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

```js
// $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
var data = [{
    "title": "Title",
    "content": [
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" },
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" },
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" }
    ]
},
{
    "title": "Title",
    "content": [
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" },
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" },
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" }
    ]
}];

for (var i in data) {
  const output = $('#output');
  const block = $('<div class="block"></div>');
  const wrap = $('<div class="wrap"></div>');
  const card = $(wrap).append('<div class="card"></div>');

  $(output).append(block).prepend('<h2>' + data[i].title + '</h2>').append(wrap);

  for (var j in data[i].content) {
    $(card).append('<h3>' + data[i].content[j].card + '</h3>')
      .append('<p><img src="' + data[i].content[j].img + '" alt="' + data[i].content[j].alt + '">' + '</p>')
      .append('<p>' + data[i].content[j].text + '</p>');
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#output {
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.wrap {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.card {
  padding: 30px 20px;
  background-color: lavenderblush;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <h1>Ajax</h1>
  <div id="output">
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: it should be working you are doing it right. Whats the issue?

Comment: It doesn't come out as I want. I want to wrap some tags (`block` , `card`) like written above (Ideally I want html to be like this:)

Comment: I've added your json into the snippet and it seems to work fine - doing something at least.  Can detail what you're trying to do that's not working?  This part of your question isn't very clear what you intend: *"how to output outside json data"*

Comment: If you have anything to add to the question, please do *edit* the question rather than add code/images as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I eddied the question.
Hope this tells what I wanna tell.
Probablly the probrem is not about ajax but jquery loop.
Still in stack though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some issues with your order of appending. Check the corrections:

```js
// $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
var data = [{
    "title": "Title",
    "content": [
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" },
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" },
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" }
    ]
},
{
    "title": "Title",
    "content": [
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" },
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" },
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" }
    ]
}];

for (var i in data) {
  const output = $('#output')
  , block = $('<div class="block"></div>')
  , wrap = $('<div class="wrap"></div>')
  

  for (var j in data[i].content) {
    const card = $('<div class="card"></div>');
      card
      .append('<h3>' + data[i].content[j].card + '</h3>')
      .append('<p><img src="' + data[i].content[j].img + '" alt="' + data[i].content[j].alt + '">' + '</p>')
      .append('<p>' + data[i].content[j].text + '</p>');
      wrap.append(card);
  }
      
  
  block.append('<h2>' + data[i].title + '</h2>');
  block.append(wrap);  
  output.append(block);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#output {
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.wrap {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.card {
  padding: 30px 20px;
  background-color: lavenderblush;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <h1>Ajax</h1>
  <div id="output">
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I need it a bit fix more.
I need to `card` tag 3 times in each `wrap` tag like below.
Is there any way to make it?
Probably, forEach loop?

Comment: @user10991526 Edited the answer, you need to define `card` each time in the loop and append inside the loop as well to `wrap`

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I got your explanation to define and append IN LOOP.
Learned a lot. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can just change $(card) to $(block)  near the end of the script

```js
// $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
var data = [{
    "title": "Title",
    "content": [
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" },
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" },
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" }
    ]
},
{
    "title": "Title",
    "content": [
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" },
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" },
        { "card": "Card Title", "text": "Text", "img": "https://picsum.photos/200/100", "alt": "Alt" }
    ]
}];

for (var i in data) {
  const output = $('#output')
  , block = $('<div class="block"></div>')
  , wrap = $('<div class="wrap"></div>')
  , card = $('<div class="card"></div>');

  for (var j in data[i].content) {
    $(block).append('<h3>' + data[i].content[j].card + '</h3>')
      .append('<p><img src="' + data[i].content[j].img + '" alt="' + data[i].content[j].alt + '">' + '</p>')
      .append('<p>' + data[i].content[j].text + '</p>');
  }
      
  wrap.append(card);
  block.append('<h2>' + data[i].title + '</h2>');
  block.append(wrap);  
  output.append(block);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#output {
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.wrap {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.card {
  padding: 30px 20px;
  background-color: lavenderblush;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <h1>Ajax</h1>
  <div id="output">
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help.